# SharePoint Versioning

Tags: versioning, status

I have a published document in an Approved status and need to make changes to it.  However, I still want the approved published document visible in the library with still an approved status, but also have the same document that I will need to work on that will be availble but with a status of In Progress.  I want to maintain the versioning as one collective document.

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled minor versioning on the document library?

Minor versions will allow you to have drafts of the document and only editors/approvers can see the draft versions (this setting can be changed).

Answer (score 0):

The approved document will still be visible to users.  *If the version is less than v1.0 normal users will not be able to see the file, as it has no approved version*.

Sharepoint limits the users that can see the documents that are in draft or pending status - [it uses Permissions to do this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sites/user-permissions-and-permission-levels).  If you are new to this, the easiest way is to test the system with a couple of colleagues, use the OOTB user groups as much as you can.

For your test there are 3 roles - one of you will be the person that makes a new draft, this person must have at least `CONTRIBUTE` permissions.  Another user will have only `READ` permissions.  Since you are the SP Admin, you can be the approver, I'm assuming therefore that you have `FULL CONTROL` (which includes the approve permission) otherwise you'll need to be in the `APPROVERS` group.

Test:

- Who can see a draft/pending document.

Depending on the Document Library settings, normally a user with READ permissions would not see draft versions or versions of files going through the approval process - this is known as [Draft Item Security](https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-approve-documents-without-building-a-workflow/).  Depending on the draft item security, only approvers or users with `FULL CONTROL` and the user that made the new draft version can see the draft.

- See what a user with `FULL CONTROL` or `APPROVE` can see compared to a user with `CONTRIBUTE` or `READ` permissions, the former groups see a lot more detail - as you see in the picture below.  Note the view name - once [content approval is enabled](https://www.dummies.com/software/microsoft-office/sharepoint/how-to-turn-on-content-approval-in-sharepoint/) on your document library, Sharepoint automatically adds this view.

[image: overview picture]